# Laravel Error Reflection Exception Function does not exist

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I'm facing this error and not able to find where the problem is as it ONLY mentions that Function () does not exist, at first I though caps problem as function F is in caps but that I not the case as I have browsed through every line of code a very many times, if someone could pinpoint it.

The scenario is like this, I have a login page with dummy seeder data in mysql. PHP form is used to validate the user and then redirects to dashboard page, but upon redirecting the error page shows up..

Screenshot if it helps.

https://postimg.org/image/8rrk1vfutn/

CheckRole.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;

class CheckRole
{
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
      $roles = $this->getRequiredRoleForRoute($request->route());
      if ($request->user()->hasRole($roles) || !$roles)
      {
        return $next($request);
      }
      return redirect()->route('noPermission');
    }

    private function getRequiredRoleForRoute($route)
    {
      $actions = $route->getAction();
      return isset($actions['roles']) ? $actions['roles'] : null;
    }
}
```

DashboardController.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class DashboardController extends Controller
{
    public function __construct ()
    {
      $this->middleware('web');
    }

    public function dashboard()
    {
      return view('layout.dashboard');
    }
}
```

LoginController.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers;
use Auth;

class LoginController extends Controller
{
    use AuthenticatesUsers;

    protected $name = 'name';
    protected $redirectTo = '/dashboard';
    protected $guard = 'web';

    public function getLogin()
    {
      if (Auth::guard('web')->check())
      {
        return redirect()->route('dashboard');
      }
      return view('login');
    }

    public function postLogin(Request $request)
    {
      $auth = Auth::guard('web')->attemp(['name'=>$request->name, 'password'=>$request->password,'active'=>1]);

      if ($auth)
      {
        return redirect()->route('dashboard');
      }
      return redirect()->route('/');
    }

    public function getLogout()
    {
      Auth::guard('web')->logout();
      return redirect()->route('/');
    }
}
```

Authen.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class Authen
{
    public function handle($request, Closure $next, $guard = 'web')
    {
      if (!Auth::guard($guard)->check())
      {
        return redirect()->route('/');
      }
        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

Added in Kernel.php

```
'roles' => \App\Http\Middleware\CheckRole::class,
'authen' => \App\Http\Middleware\Authen::class,
```

Role.php

```
<?php
namespace App;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
class Role extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'roles';
    protected $fillable = 'name';
    protected $primaryKey = 'id';
    public $timestamps = false;

    public function users()
    {
       return $this->hasMany('App\User', 'role_id', 'id');
    }
}
```

User.php

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable;

    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'email', 'password', 'active', 'role_id',
    ];

    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];

    public function role()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('App\Role', 'id', 'role_id');
    }

    private function checkIfUserHasRole($need_role)
    {
        return ($need_role == $this->role->name) ? true : null;
    }

    public function hasRole()
    {
        if (s_array($roles))
        {
            foreach($roles as $need_role)
            {
                if($this->checkIfUserHasRole($need_role))
                {
                    return true;
                }
            }
          }
            else
            {
                return $this->checkIfUserHasRole($roles);
            }
            return false;
        }
}
```

web.php

```
<?php

Route::get('/', ['as'=>'/', 'uses'=>'LoginController@getLogin']);
Route::post('/login', ['as'=>'login', 'LoginController@postLogin']);

Route::group(['middleware'=>['authen', 'roles']], function()
             {
               Route::get('/logout', ['as'=>'logout', 'uses'=>'LoginController@getLogout']);
                 Route::get('/dashboard', ['as'=>'dashboard', 'uses'=>'DashboardController@dashboard']);
             });
```

UsersTableSeeder

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;
use App\User;
class UsersTableSeeder extends Seeder
{
    public function run()
    {
        User::create([
          'role_id'=>1,
          'active'=>1,
          'name'=>'James',
          'email'=>'James@yahoo.com',
          'password'=>bcrypt('james'),
          'remember_token'=>str_random(10)
        ]);
    }
}
```

RolesTableSeeder

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;
use App\Role;
class RolesTableSeeder extends Seeder
{
    public function run()
    {
        Role::insert([
          ['name'=>'Admin'],
          ['name'=>'Student'],
          ['name'=>'Teacher']
        ]);
    }
}
```

Apologies for the lengthy code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot using uses in /login route.
It would be like this

```
Route::post('/login', ['as'=>'login', 'uses'=>'LoginController@postLogin']);
```

Comment: Thanks, that command made it work perfect, appreciate however when I try to upvote it says my reputation is less than 15 so I cannot upvote. Thanks again..

Comment: That's okay. You can accept my answer by clicking Green Tick button.

Answer (score 3):

For those who are coming from google, in my case was i typo

```
    Route::get("document-types", [DocumentTypesController::class], "index");
```

Instead of

```
    Route::get("document-types", [DocumentTypesController::class, "index"]);
```

Comment: Thanks, in my case the typo was that I added a dot instead of a comma.